# Instalar ADT BUNDLE en Windows 10

Tags: android-studio

me descargue el Android Studio Bundle que viene ya con las herramientas necesarias para comenzar a programar en Android. El problema es que lo ejecuto y no inicia el instalador. Lo ejecuto también como Administrador y nada. A alguien le ha ocurrido algo similar que pueda ayudarme.

Comment: Windows 10 es de 32 o 64 bits?

Comment: El SO es de 64 bits

Comment: Agrega a tu pregunta los que se reporta en el .log que se encuentra en el path C:\Users\<USUARIO>\.AndroidStudio2.1\system\log

Comment: Es que nisiquiera comienza la instalación del programa. Simplemente no lo ejecuta

Comment: Si revisas el Log, es la forma más sencilla de obtener que causa se cierre Android Studio =)